# "Talking to" or "talking with"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct, and what is the difference in their meaning?

> I'll talk **with** Stuart and get back to you.
>
> I'll talk **to** Stuart and get back to you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Talk with* theoretically implies a dialogue, *talk to* implies a monologue.

> I talked with my family and we've decided to buy a new car.

-> We had a conversation about whether we need a car.

> I found out my son is smoking, so I talked to him. I hope my words will change the way he thinks.

-> I was talking to him and he listened to what I said.

*Talk to* can result in a dialogue, of course, but marks the initial intention of a serious monologue, like:

> I'm going to talk to my boss today and ask for a raise.

-> I will go to his office, give a serious speech and hopefully it will result in a rational dialogue.

> We're having a party tonight and my boss will be there, so I'm sure I'll talk with him a lot.

-> We will have a casual conversation, but nothing too serious I'd like to give a speech about.

Another example would be:

> My conscience talks to me.

-> Because it usually tells you what to do. You never have a conversation with it, therefore you **never** hear this:

> My conscience talks with me.

Comment: +1: Mostly I agree, but wouldn't say this is an ironclad distinction. There is a lot of overlap between the two.